# What causes the bright flash of light when poking my eye?

Tags: vision, neurophysiology, human-eye

Recently, I poked myself in between my eye and eye socket, right below my eyebrow, and sometimes I would get this flash of light. Others have tried this too, and they also had a flash of light. I am wondering why is this the case. Does it have to do with the nerves in the eye?

Comment: Yes. You somehow stimulated your optic nerve.

Comment: Im probly stating the obvious here but i reckon you should probly go to the doctor for this one:)

Comment: @MattDMo so really, I am really asking which optic nerve I stimulated?

Comment: I would like to point out to you that that is exactly what Isaac Newton did and set off his interest in light. I hope you become like him! ;) (you might find this interesting: http://www.psmag.com/health-and-behavior/newtons-needle-scientific-self-experimentation-86583 or even watch http://www.ensemblestudiotheatre.org/isaacs-eye-lucas-hnath)

Comment: @TanMath - there's only one "optic nerve" per eye. That's the name for the bundle of nerves, made up of (?hundreds of thousands?) of nerve cells receiving signals from various nerve endings in the eye.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer**
Pressure phosphenes are believed to be induced by stretch-induced activation of retinal ganglion cells.

**Background**
Flashes of light (phosphenes) due to pressure on the eye ball are referred to as [pressure phosphenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphene). Based on an electrophysiological study ([Grüsser *et al*., 1989](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0042698989901235)), eyeball indentation presumably tangentially stretches the [retina](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/002291.htm) locally, which variably depolarizes [horizontal cells](http://webvision.med.utah.edu/book/part-v-phototransduction-in-rods-and-cones/horizontal-cells/). This in turn depolarizes ON-[bipolar ganglion cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retina_bipolar_cell), while hyperpolarizing OFF-bipolars. Some ON-center neurons also seem to respond to the removal of the deformation. Bipolar cells connect to the [retinal ganglion cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retinal_ganglion_cell). These ganglion cells carry visual information from the retina via their axons in the [optic nerve](http://www.healthline.com/human-body-maps/optic-nerve) to the brain. Hence, to answer your question: yes, pressure phosphenes are related to activity in the optic nerve.

<sub>**Reference**

**-** [Grüsser *et al*., *Vis Res* (1989); **29**(2): 181–94](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0042698989901235)</sub>